# Twilight Zone (TOS) Visual Riddle #2

Tags: riddle, visual

This puzzle suggests either an actor or a character from the original Twilight Zone.

There's another possibility besides the one posted below by Avi. Hint: this puzzle has a connection to Puzzle #1.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

> Jay Overholts ("J over holes"). Appeared in 8 episodes of TOS.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of Google searching brings up:

> **Jonathan Hole** ("J on hole" is "Jon Hole", which is what you might call this actor).

Apparently,

> he acted in Season 1 Episode 35 of The Twilight Zone, ["The Mighty Casey"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734661/), as the Team Doctor.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for that info! Not who I had in mind, though.

I guess it's time for a clue: this puzzle has a connection to puzzle #1.